# zsh regex failing, bug or user error?

Tags: regex, zsh

This regex works (stripping out `-search`)

```
[~%]for i  in foo*-search-aae-status ; do echo $i(:s/-search//) ; done
foo1-aae-status
foo2-aae-status
foo3-aae-status
foo4-aae-status
foo5-aae-status
```

But this regex (trying to strip out everything after `-` doesn't)

```
[~%]for i  in foo*-search-aae-status ; do echo $i(:s/-*//) ; done
foo1-search-aae-status
foo2-search-aae-status
foo3-search-aae-status
foo4-search-aae-status
foo5-search-aae-status
```

Am I missing something? I've tried `.*` but that just gets ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to llua from freenode irc.

> you could enable hist_subst_pattern to do what i think you are trying to do

```
[%]setopt hist_subst_pattern
[%]print $TXT:s/-*//
foo1
```